# Android Studio cant find or install play-services 7 /wearable

Tags: android-studio, windows-8.1, android-sdk-manager

I have a new windows 8.1 machine, and am trying to get my android IDE environment installed.  But there seems to be some issues that i have never encountered before.  my existing projects are not compiling because the system can not find or even download the proper play services libs..

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':mobile:_debugCompile'.
> >     A problem occurred configuring project ':wear'.
> >     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':wear:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.0.0.
> >                Searched in the following locations:
> >                    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/7.0.0/play-services-wearable-7.0.0.pom
> >                    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/7.0.0/play-services-wearable-7.0.0.jar
> >                    file:/C:/Users/Erik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/7.0.0/play-services-wearable-7.0.0.pom
> >                    file:/C:/Users/Erik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/7.0.0/play-services-wearable-7.0.0.jar
> >                    file:/C:/Users/Erik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/7.0.0/play-services-wearable-7.0.0.pom
> >                    file:/C:/Users/Erik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-wearable/7.0.0/play-services-wearable-7.0.0.jar
> >                Required by:
> >                    AndroidClickDogTrainer:wear:unspecified

So i tried using the SDK manager to insure i had the proper play services but
I keep getting the following error from my SDK manager in Android Studio on my Windows 8.1 machine.

This is a clean install, and i thought it may be my firewall settings but after turning off my firewall completely it is still happening:

> Refresh Sources:   Fetched Add-ons List successfully   Refresh Sources
>   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: File not
>   found   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml,
>   reason: File not found   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml,
>   reason: File not found   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml/addon.xml,
>   reason: File not found Refresh Sources:   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: File not
>   found   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml,
>   reason: File not found   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml,
>   reason: File not found   Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml/addon.xml,
>   reason: File not found Ignoring unknown package filter
>   'extra-google-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all
>   packages. There is nothing to install.
>            Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

No matter what i do.. TURN OFF FIRE WALL, RUN AS ADMIN.. etc etc.. it just won't install the play services libs..

please help

Answer (score 0):

So I searched high and low for an answer to this, and it seems a lot of people are having this and similar issues and creating really cumbersome workarounds that include everything from re-writing parts of the android.bat file to uninstalling the SDK and re-installing it from scratch.. for me none of those solutions worked.. but what seems to have fixed the problem was actually quite simple.

hope this helps others..

open the Android SDK Manager.. click on TOOLS>Options and check "Force https://.. sources to be fetched using http://.."